# XCM transaction via polkadot.js/api possible?

Tags: polkadot-js, xcm, bridge

How to do XCM transaction via polkadot.js/api?
I just need to do something like that: https://apps.karura.network/bridge.

Comment: Guess it depends what they are doing under the covers. Do you have an example transaction that you can point to that was created using this UI? I'm guessing they are doing a reserve asset transfer with the relay chain as the reserve and then minting a derivative ksm token on the karura parachain to represent your actual ksm holding that is in karura's sovereign parachain account on the relay chain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can send XCMs via the [`xcm-pallet`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/pallet_xcm/pallet/enum.Call.html) interface, using both polkadot.js apps and api, in the same was as you would send any other transaction.